# Creating a grid of divs from two input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given two input fields, I would like to create a grid that takes the first input as the rows, and second input as the columns, and appears once a separate button is clicked.

I know how to make a grid NxN, but I want a grid NxY, that specifically gets created via a button.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector("#gridDiv");
const rowSize = document.querySelector("#rowInput");
const colSize = document.querySelector("columnInput");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

function NxY(n, y) {
  let rowsArr = [];
  let columnArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    columnArr.push(i);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    rowsArr.push(columnArr);
  }
  render(rowsArr)
}

function render(arr) {
  arr.forEach((items) => {
    let outerDiv = document.createElement("div")
    outerDiv.classList.add("row");
    items.forEach((item) => {
      let dv = document.createElement("div");
      dv.classList.add("cell");
      outerDiv.appendChild(dv);
    });
    grid.appendChild(outerDiv);
  });
}
NxY(3, 4);
```

This will automatically produce the grid specified at the bottom, but my issue is figuring out how to add an eventListener to the button that will correctly guide it to creating the proper grid.

Comment: can you clarify what you have and what goes wrong ?  from this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PMjWdR  or a jsfiddle or the snippet from your question

Comment: what do you mean by a grid ? Is a matrix for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet

```js
$('#btnInsert').click(function(){
$('#mtable tbody').html('');
var row_count = $('#row').val();
var col_count = $('#col').val();
    if(row_count && col_count){
     //entry is valid
    while(row_count > 0){
     //add new row
        $('#mtable tbody').append($("<tr>"));  
      row_count--;
        }
        while(col_count > 0){
        //add new column
        $('#mtable tr').append($("<td>")); 
        $('#mtable tbody tr').each(function(){$(this).children('td:last').append($('<input type="checkbox">'))});
      col_count--;
        }
    }else{alert('Invalid entry');}
}); 

$('#btnInsert2').click(function(){
$('#mDiv').html('');
var row_count = $('#row2').val();
var col_count = $('#col2').val();
    if(row_count && col_count){
     //entry is valid
    while(row_count > 0){
     //add new row
        $('#mDiv').append($("<div class='row'>"));  
      row_count--;
        }
        while(col_count > 0){ 
        //add new column
        $('#mDiv').children('.row').each(function(){$(this).append($('<div class="col col-md-4">'))});
      col_count--;
        }
    }else{alert('Invalid entry');}
});
```

```css
td{padding:5px;}
.col{margin:5px;
     min-height: 50px;
     background: #aaaaaa;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>For Tables </h3>
<input id="row" type="number" max="20" placeholder="Enter no. of rows"/> 
<input id="col" type="number" max="20" placeholder="Enter no. of columns"/>
<button id="btnInsert">Generate Grid</button>
<table border="1" id="mtable"> 
    <tbody></tbody>
</table><br/><br/><br/><br/>


<h3>For Divs </h3>
<input id="row2" type="number" max="20" placeholder="Enter no. of rows"/> 
<input id="col2" type="number" max="20" placeholder="Enter no. of columns"/>
<button id="btnInsert2">Generate Grid</button>
<br>
<div class="container" id="mDiv"></div><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```